# Purpose of z3::tactic and z3::goal

Tags: z3

I see that I can create goals, add them to a tactic, and create a solver from the tactic.

What is the advantage of this approach over simply creating a z3::solver instance and adding my expressions to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tactics have a different purpose. You can create a goal that contains your assertions/constraints and then you run a Tactic ON the goal, the result of which will be a new set of (sub-)goals, i.e., new assertions/constraints. Solvers determine satisfiability and won't produce new (sub-)goals.

Tactics can be converted into solvers, such that the resulting solver will run the tactic, and if the result is conclusive (trivial sat/unsat), it will return that result. If the sub-goals produced by the tactic are not conclusive, it will return "unknown".